# Nginx caching issue ( 200 OK (from disk cache) )

Tags: linux, nginx, system-administration

Hi Can anybody tell why i am getting this caching from disk on an nginx web server.

I am worried that the changes we made are not visible to visitor of the site. How can we disable this cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to disable cache, but the changes you make are visible to customers in a maximum of 1 day. that cache doesn't bother you at all. I had the same problem. But if you want to see your site urgently, you can use:

```
https://yourdomain.com/?what-ever-you-want
```

After '?' you can set anything you want, but you have to change every time, because it acts as a variable and stores the current cache, setting aside the previous one. For visitors the changes will definitely be made. Do not worry.